# convert columns into rows pandas

Tags: python, pandas

So my df has some information by store ,type of product (price) , and date

the problem is that the tree different products are in columns but I need in rows.

For example my df looks like this:

| Store | PRODUCT X | PRODUCT Y | product z | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aaa | $$$$ | $$$$ | . $$$$ | 2021/02/07 |
| bbb | $$$$ | $$$$ | . $$$$ | . |

and I want to look like

| Store | PRODUCTS | PRICE. | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aaa | PRODUCT X | $$$$ | 2021/02/07 |
| aaa | PRODUCT y | $$$$ | 2021/02/07 |
| aaa | PRODUCT z | $$$$ | 2021/02/07 |
| bbb | PRODUCT X | $$$$ | 2021/02/07 |
| bbb | PRODUCT y | $$$$ | 2021/02/07 |
| bbb | PRODUCT z | $$$$ | 2021/02/07 |

Comment: [`wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html)

Comment: you can use https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html